# Cell range not linking between two sheets in workbook (Google spreadsheet)

Tags: google-apps-script

I am new to google spreadsheet functions and trying to apply formula in following way:

I have sheet1 & sheet2 in one workbook (name-formula1).

I want to link range data from sheet2 & range a1:a10 in sheet1 and cell A2, formula mentioned is as under:

```
=Sheet2!A1:A10
```

Now concern is that it is displaying only one item (last one) from the range whereby it was supposed to display ten items (a1:a10)

Please look the following link for detail and help in correcting above formula:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HX1eatP57A5k9Xku7awIVnBPQ2A4ICVrYXTsTOza9Cg/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to wrap that in an index() or arrayformula().. So try:

```
=Arrayformula(Sheet2!A1:A10)
```

Comment: Please answer following question also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29431786/extract-two-words-from-a-cell-in-to-another-cell-in-google-spreadsheet