# Extract two words from a cell in to another cell in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new to google spreadsheets & want to copy class names mentioned in range c10 in to b3. I am trying to use following formula which I know is wrong:

```
=query(C3:C52, "copy class name where C contains 'class' in cell c10 ")
```

C10 cell contains following data:

```
<body bgcolor="beige" class="body"> <div class="big_wrapper">
```

I want following two words to appear in cell b3:

```
body big_wrapper
```

Please correct above formula.

For more clarity visit sheet1 of following link:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HfgOqprc-P34vOI-nGAionllrGAOsMOVuLB5ozboWBY/edit#gid=0

Comment: Looking at your posting patterns, seems like you are much more interested in getting your work done instead of learning how to do it, not a right approach.

Comment: Actually I am trying to make a system which will include jquery, html and css, I am taking help of spreadsheets to keep the class codes & jquery functions, it is difficult to describe but it will help in my project and so far I have learnt what I got, but frankly telling I really know very less about google spreadsheet data functions, so please help in solving above question

Comment: Try using the =search function instead of =query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be easier ways, but try (in B3):

```
=join(" ", regexextract(C10, "class="&char(34)&"(.+?)"&char(34)&">.+class="&char(34)&"(.+?)"&char(34)&">"))
```

Comment: Please solve this question:    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29633667/exclude-dates-from-a-range-in-google-spreadsheets