# Exclude dates from a range in google spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am new to google spreadsheets & trying to exclude dates from a range in google spreadsheet in following way.

I have following cells in range (c2:c7):

4/9/2015 9:21:09

4/9/2015 17:50:24

4/10/2015 17:25:57

4/11/2015 17:07:00

4/13/2015 18:13:35

4/14/2015 17:00:58

I want to exclude all dates and want following range in B2:

9:21:09

17:50:24

17:25:57

17:07:00

18:13:35

17:00:58

I have tried using regexextract function but could not succeed, can anybody help please, I have mentioned this in following link:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tsmeLz_TZ_nm_1M40bzM7cKq9mU_FUeFxdsk0fnL6wo/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ArrayFormula(mod(C2:C7,1))
```

where C2:C7 is the range with the timestamp. Format the column with the output as TIME (via the 123-button)

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex.

```
/(two numbers):(two numbers):(two numbers)/
```

After pulling each of these parts from the dates, save them into an array and set them in column B. (It's preferred to copy to a 2D Array then use `Range.setValues()` for speed).

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
=TEXT(A1,"HH:MM:SS")
```